# Join all results of a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, postgresql-9.6

So I want to `LEFT JOIN` all files that are referenced by at least one of multiple columns:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    O o
    LEFT JOIN binary_stream_value bsv ON o.binary_stream_value_id = bsv.id
    LEFT JOIN artwork art ON o.artwork_id = art.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT f.id FROM file f WHERE f.id = bsv.file_id OR f.id = art.file_id) f ON TRUE
    ...
```

This fails with

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "bsv"
LINE 212: ...  LEFT JOIN (SELECT f.id FROM file f WHERE f.id = bsv.file_i...
                                                               ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "bsv", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Admittedly, I half expected this to fail, half hoped I was wrong.

What's the proper way of writing such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lateral join for what you want to do:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    O o
    LEFT JOIN binary_stream_value bsv ON o.binary_stream_value_id = bsv.id
    LEFT JOIN artwork art ON o.artwork_id = art.id
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT f.id FROM file f WHERE f.id = bsv.file_id OR f.id = art.file_id) f ON TRUE
    ...
```

But the sub-select isn't really necessary to begin with:

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    O o
    LEFT JOIN binary_stream_value bsv ON o.binary_stream_value_id = bsv.id
    LEFT JOIN artwork art ON o.artwork_id = art.id
    LEFT JOIN file f on f.id = bsv.file_id OR f.id = art.file_id
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, for me the sub-select is useless, it's just a join with condition in the `ON`

Comment: Well, looks like my brain just insisted it needed to be more complex. XD Thanks!